# Unwanted SQLite inserted in \bin

Tags: sqlite, deployment, elmah

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and using web deployment to promote the .Net MVC site to specific environments.  I installed Elmah, and it worked great on my DEV environment, but when I pushed TEST, I got exceptions because SQLite was not a good format.

I am not using SQLite in Elmah or otherwise that I know of.  I have removed all visible refernces to SQLite, and I have removed the .dll from all configuration bin directories.  But it still gets inserted with each build.  I realize the exception problem is that SQLite cannot be built for CPU Any, and my environments vary from x86 to x64.  But I would prefer SQLite to not even be present.

I have since uninstalled Elmah, and SQLite is still inserted into the \bin directory.  I have now re-installed Elmah, and I manually delete the SQLite.dll from \bin after each build.  How can I determine what is causing SQLite to be inserted into my \bin after each build?

Comment: I am not clear on this: Did you removed SQLite from the Elmah Source Code and re-compile it?

Comment: Stefan, I did not remove any references from the Elmah source.  I simply used the Elmah binaries.  Sounds like I'll have to touch their pristine code.  I'll get into the source.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are not using SQLite then you need to simply remove it from the *source* location from where you *imported* the reference. To expand on that, let's assume you downloaded and unzipped ELMAH to the path `C:\ELMAH` on your local drive. When you added a reference to ELMAH, you probably pointed to one of the platform versions under `C:\ELMAH\bin`, like `C:\ELMAH\bin\net-2.0\Release`. From  `C:\ELMAH\bin` sub-directories, remove all other unwanted assemblies and files except `Elmah.dll`, `Elmah.pdb` and `Elmah.xml`. Strictly speaking, you don't even need the latter two but they are nonetheless recommended. Once you've done that, you can add a reference to `Elmah.dll` to your project in Visual Studio and none of the dependencies will get pulled into your application's `bin` directory. You may have to delete your `bin` directory and re-build your project to get rid of a stale copy of `System.Data.SQLite.dll` from a previous reference. ELMAH will continue to work fine without `System.Data.SQLite.dll` as long as you do not use `Elmah.SQLiteErrorLog` as your error log store.

As per other suggestions, you should not have to remove references to SQLite from the ELMAH sources and make a private build.

Comment: While Stefan's answer accomplishes my objective with little effort, Atif's solution solves the problem without touching the source.  This is really what I was looking for.  Besides, who am I to argue with Atif when it comes to Elmah.

Comment: While this approach does work it results in VS2010 MSBUILD warning CA0060 if you have code analysis turned on for the project referencing Elmah. I cannot find any way to suppress this warning. So the toss up is: have unnecessary assemblies in my project dependencies, or live with code analysis warnings. I don't like either...

Comment: Any suggestions for NuGet users? If I grab the Elmah package in NuGet it throws the SQLite dll in my bin directory on every build.

Answer (score 2):

I think Visual Studio will detect that SQLite is required by Elmah and copy it if it finds it. In order to achive the same goal as you I removed all SQLite stuff from the Elmah source code and re-built it. It is quite painless thing to do...

Comment: Cha Ching! Just remove SQLiteErrorLog.cs from the project, build and go.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use a text editor with "find-in-files" support to search all your project files for "sqlite".  Something must be referencing it.

Comment: Sam, thanks.  I did a find in file, but no reference to SQLite was found.

Answer (score 0):

I know that is an old question, but I have a similar problem and landed here, so perhaps my answer is still helpful for others.

Simply add this to your project file of your web application in a prefered PropertyGroup-element:

```
<ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>bin\System.Data.SQLite.dll</ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>
```