# How to get Visual Studio 'Publish' option to delete file from bin directory?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, publish

I have a web application which, when published using the "Publish" option within Visual Studio, outputs a DLL **System.Data.SQLite.dll** in the bin direcotry.

When deployed, this dll causes problem so I have to delete each time after publishing.

Is there a way of automatically deleting ths file from the bin directory in what is 'published'?

**SOLUTION:**

I was actually referencing Elmah.dll which then pulls in System.Data.SQLite.dll automatically. The solution is to delete the System.Data.SQLite.dll from the directory from which Elmah.dll is being referenced from.

I found the solution here: [Unwanted SQLite inserted in bin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814101/unwanted-sqlite-inserted-in-bin)

Answer (score 3):

Open up the **Reference** section under **Solution Explorer**, right click on the reference you would like not to publish and hit **Properties** (pressing <kbd>F4</kbd> would do the same).

Under **Properties**, you will find an option named **Local Copy**. Set it to `false`. This should do the trick.